# Parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

[image]

(Picture is small, here is another link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO9jb.png)

I'm trying to extract the text of the review at the bottom. I've tried this:

```
y = soup.find_all("div", style = "margin-left:0.5em;")
review = y[0].text
```

The problem is that there is unwanted text in the unexpanded `div` tags that becomes tedious to remove from the content of the review. For the life of me, I just can't figure this out. Could someone please help me?

Edit: The HTML is:

```
div style="margin-left:0.5em;">
    <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;"> 9 of 35 people found the following review helpful </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
    <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
    <div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
        <b>
    </div>
    That is true. I tried it myself this morning. There's a little note on the Audible site that says "a few titles will require two credits" or something like that. A Dance with Dragons is one of those few.
```

The div tag above the text is as follows:

```
<div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
    <b>
        <span class="h3color tiny">This review is from: </span>
        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005C7QVUE" rel="nofollow noreferrer">A Dance with Dragons: A Song of Ice and Fire: Book 5 (Audible Audio Edition)</a>
    </b>
</div>
That is true. I tried it myself this morning. There's a little note on the Audible site that says "a few titles will require two credits" or something like that. A Dance with Dragons is one of those few.
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings suggests that the .strings method is what you want - it returns a iterator of each string within the object. So if you turn that iterator into a list and take the last item, you should get what you want. For example:

```
$ python
>>> import bs4
>>> text = '<div style="mine"><div>unwanted</div>wanted</div>'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> soup.find_all("div", style="mine")[0].text
u'unwantedwanted'
>>> list(soup.find_all("div", style="mine")[0].strings)[-1]
u'wanted'
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the text in the tail of `div.tiny`:

```py
review = soup.find("div", "tiny").findNextSibling(text=True)
```

Full example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div style="margin-left:0.5em;">
<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
   9 of 35 people found the following review helpful </div>
<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
<div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
<div class="tiny" style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
<b>
    <span class="h3color tiny">This review is from: </span>
    <a href="http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005C7QVUE">
     A Dance with Dragons: A Song of Ice and Fire: Book 5 (Audible Audio Edition)</a>
</b>
</div>
That is true. I tried it myself this morning. There's a little note on the Audible site that says "a few titles will require two credits" or something like that. A Dance with Dragons is one of those few."""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
review = soup.find("div", "tiny").findNextSibling(text=True)
print(review)
```

#### Output

```
That is true. I tried it myself this morning. There's a little note on the Audible site that says "a few titles will require two credits" or something like that. A Dance with Dragons is one of those few.
```

Here's an equivalent `lxml` code that produces the same output:

```py
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
print doc.find(".//div[@class='tiny']").tail
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the text isn't under that div tag with class tiny. It's under the main div tag with style margin-left:0.5em;

Comment: @user1709173: does it work?  If not, post actual html (as text, not a picture) that provides enough context i.e., include elements around the text. "tail" is immediately after the "tiny" element so next sibling should work.

Comment: Sorry. I posted the HTML in an edit to my original post. Expanding the nested div tags would eventually reveal text, but it gets a bit lengthy so that isn't included in my edit.

Comment: @user1709173: I've tried my code with your html and it works. What results do you get?

Comment: I get '\n'. I posted the expansion of the div tag with class tiny in my original post. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @user1709173: what do you get if you run the full example posted above?