# Extract content of <p> tags when other tags are present

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract both the text within the  tag and the bit after in the following bit of html, using beautiful soup:

```
<p><i>Italic stuff</i> Not Italic stuff</p>
```

So I do

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p><i>Italic stuff</i> Not Italic stuff</p>')
ital = soup.i.string
notital = soup.string
```

But the soup.string returns None, instead of 'Not Italic stuff... What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of the `.string` property:

> If this tag has a single string child, return value  is that string.
>   If this tag has no children, or more than one  child, return value is
>   None. If this tag has one child tag,  return value is the 'string'
>   attribute of the child tag,  recursively.

What you seem to need is to extract the tailing text of the `i` element, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062965/1258041):

```
In [12]: soup.i.findNextSibling(text=True)
Out[12]: u' Not Italic stuff'
```

Comment: Indeed that works, thanks a lot. Seems like a lot of obfuscation for such a simple thing...

Answer (score -1):

## Utility function to remove tags

```
def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

   for tag in soup.findAll(True):
      if tag.name in invalid_tags:
         s = ""
       for c in tag.contents:
           if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
               c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
           s += unicode(c)

       tag.replaceWith(s)

 return soup
```

## Use method to remove tags accordingly

```
        Invalid tags which we want to remove from the content
        invalid_tags = ['p', 'div', 'a', 'strong', 'img', 'span', 'br', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h5', 'h6', 'em']
```