# How would I get the text AFTER a link in Python with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know how to go though and find all the links, but I want the text immediately after a link.

For example, in the given html:

```
<p><a href="/cgi-bin/bdquery/?&amp;Db=d106&amp;querybd=@FIELD(FLD004+@4((@1(Rep+Armey++Richard+K.))+00028))">Rep Armey, Richard K.</a> [TX-26]
 - 11/9/1999
<br/><a href="/cgi-bin/bdquery/?&amp;Db=d106&amp;querybd=@FIELD(FLD004+@4((@1(Rep+Davis++Thomas+M.))+00274))">Rep Davis, Thomas M.</a> [VA-11]
 - 11/9/1999
<br/><a href="/cgi-bin/bdquery/?&amp;Db=d106&amp;querybd=@FIELD(FLD004+@4((@1(Rep+DeLay++Tom))+00282))">Rep DeLay, Tom</a> [TX-22]
 - 11/9/1999
```

... (this repeats a number of times)

I want to extract the `[CA-28] - 11/9/1999` that is associated with `<a href=... >Rep Dreier, David</a>`

and do this for all of the links in the list

Comment: [findNextSibling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14062965/111424)? Can't install BeautifulSoup just now at my site to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[findNextSibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#findNextSiblings%28name,%20attrs,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29%20and%20findNextSibling%28name,%20attrs,%20text,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) is a robust and flexible way to do it.

**The Setup**

Use this to set up.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

markup = '''
<p><a href="/cgi-bin/...00028))">Rep Armey, Richard K.</a> [TX-26]
 - 11/9/1999
<br/><a href="/cgi-bin/...00274))">Rep Davis, Thomas M.</a> [VA-11]
 - 11/9/1999
<br/><a href="/cgi-bin/...00282))">Rep DeLay, Tom</a> [TX-22]
 - 11/9/1999
 '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
```

What we do here:

- Import BeautifulSoup to slurp the soup
- Import pprint to inspect intermediate results with pretty-printing
- Paste the sample markup (with hrefs truncated) into a variable
- Slurp the markup so we can shred it

The hrefs are truncated for clarity. The result is the same on the original sample.

**Find all the links**

Call findAll with 'a':

```
links = soup.findAll('a')
pprint(links)
```

pprint shows the markup of each link.

```
[<a href="/cgi-bin/...00028))">Rep Armey, Richard K.</a>,
 <a href="/cgi-bin/...00274))">Rep Davis, Thomas M.</a>,
 <a href="/cgi-bin/...00282))">Rep DeLay, Tom</a>]
```

**Get the text following an element**

Call findNextSibling with text=True.

```
text_0 = links[0].findNextSibling(text=True)
pprint(text_0)
```

pprint shows the text following the first link, newlines encoded as `\n`.

```
u' [TX-26]\n - 11/9/1999\n'
```

**Do it for all links**

Use findNextSibling in a list comprehension to get the text following each link.

```
next_text = [ln.findNextSibling(text=True) for ln in links]
pprint(next_text)
```

pprint shows a list of the text, one item per link in the markup.

```
[u' [TX-26]\n - 11/9/1999\n',
 u' [VA-11]\n - 11/9/1999\n',
 u' [TX-22]\n - 11/9/1999\n ']
```

Answer (score 5):

There may be a prettier way, but I usually chain `.next`:

```
>>> soup.find_all("a")
[<a href="/cgi-bin/bdquery/?&amp;Db=d106&amp;querybd=@FIELD(FLD004+@4((@1(Rep+Armey++Richard+K.))+00028))">Rep Armey, Richard K.</a>, <a href="/cgi-bin/bdquery/?&amp;Db=d106&amp;querybd=@FIELD(FLD004+@4((@1(Rep+Davis++Thomas+M.))+00274))">Rep Davis, Thomas M.</a>, <a href="/cgi-bin/bdquery/?&amp;Db=d106&amp;querybd=@FIELD(FLD004+@4((@1(Rep+DeLay++Tom))+00282))">Rep DeLay, Tom</a>]
>>> [a.next for a in soup.find_all("a")]
[u'Rep Armey, Richard K.', u'Rep Davis, Thomas M.', u'Rep DeLay, Tom']
>>> [a.next.next for a in soup.find_all("a")]
[u' [TX-26]\n - 11/9/1999\n', u' [VA-11]\n - 11/9/1999\n', u' [TX-22]\n - 11/9/1999']
>>> {a.next: a.next.next for a in soup.find_all("a")}
{u'Rep Davis, Thomas M.': u' [VA-11]\n - 11/9/1999\n', u'Rep DeLay, Tom': u' [TX-22]\n - 11/9/1999', u'Rep Armey, Richard K.': u' [TX-26]\n - 11/9/1999\n'}
```

etc.

Comment: I ended up going with Iain Elder's answer. `findNextSibling` helped me do a few other things I needed to do, but this too was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @andymcevoy: no worries!  It's often the case that someone (in this case me!) posts a lower-level way which works and then someone else gives a more useful answer.