# Remove <del> tag with .decompose() in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to scrape a website, and am having trouble using `decompose()` to remove a `<del>` tag inside the section I'm scraping.

All products on the page have a price inside a `<div>` with the class `product-card__price`. However, some products are discounted and contain two prices in this `<div>`. The full price is contained in a tag (`<del>$</del>`) which precedes the current price.

```
# Example 1 - one price
<div class="flex-split__item product-card__price">
    $11.99          
</div>
# Example 2 - two prices
<div class="flex-split__item product-card__price">
   <del>$9.99</del> 
   $8.99          
</div>
```

If I simply grab the text in this `div` with `price = container.find(class_ = 'product-card__price').text.strip()`, Example #2 will return `$9.99  $8.99`. Reading the documentation, I thought that I should be able to use `decompose()` to strip out the text contained in `<del></del>` with the following code:

```
if container.find(class_ = 'product-card__price'):
   if container.find('del'):
      full_price = container.find('del').text.strip()
      current_price = container.find(class_ = 'product-card__price').decompose()
   else:
      full_price = None
      price = container.find(class_ = 'product-card__price').text.strip()
else:
   price = None
   full_price = None
```

However, this returns the result `None`. I'm able to split the string with Regexp, but would like to understand what I am doing wrong with decompose/extract. Example webpage is [here](https://gtfoitsvegan.com/shop/?v=7516fd43adaa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting `full_price` and `price` you don't have to `.extract()`/`.decompose()` the `<del>` tag. All it needs is to use simple `str.split()`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://gtfoitsvegan.com/shop/?v=7516fd43adaa"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for product in soup.select(".product-card"):
    prices = product.select_one(".product-card__price").text.split()
    if len(prices) == 2:
        full_price, price = prices
    else:
        full_price = "-"
        price = prices[0]

    title = product.select_one(".product-card__title").get_text(strip=True)

    print("{:<65}{:<7}{:<7}".format(title, full_price, price))
```

Prints:

```
Italian Sausage Meatballs by Hungry Planet                       -      $7.99  
Pork Gyoza by Hungry Planet                                      -      $7.99  
Asian Pork Meatballs by Hungry Planet                            -      $6.29  
Grilled and Diced Chicken by Hungry Planet                       -      $7.99  
Grilled Chicken Strips by Hungry Planet                          -      $7.99  
Crispy Fried Chicken Patties by Hungry Planet                    -      $7.99  
New England Style Crab Cakes by Hungry Planet                    -      $11.99 
Ground Beef by Hungry Planet                                     $9.99  $8.99  
Burger Patties by Hungry Planet                                  $11.99 $9.99  
Southwest Chipotle Chicken Patties by Hungry Planet              -      $11.99 
Italian Jack Sausages by Jack & Annie’s                          -      $8.69  
Apple Jack Sausages by Jack & Annie’s                            -      $8.69  
Sliced Mozzarella Soy Cheese by Tofutti                          -      $4.69  
Train Your Dragon Smoothie / Pitaya Bowl by Rollin’ n Bowlin’    -      $6.89  
Organic Mini Thyme Leaf by Simply Organic                        -      $2.49  
Organic Mini Rosemary Leaf by Simply Organic                     -      $2.49  
Organic Mini Onion Powder by Simply Organic                      -      $2.49  
Organic Mini Ground Cumin by Simply Organic                      -      $2.49  
Chick’n Pieces By Like Meat                                      -      $8.59  
BBQ Chick’n By Like Meat                                         -      $8.59  
Nuggets by Like Meat                                             -      $8.59  
Grilled Chick’n by Like Meat                                     -      $8.59  
Zalmon Sashimi 10.9oz by Vegan Zeastar                           -      $15.99 
Very Good Dog by The Very Good Butchers                          -      $7.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062965/8627992), you can find the Text by finding the `<del>` element and take its next sibling including text:

```
price = container.find("del").find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
```